# Cloudinary Android sdk take too much time to uplaod

Tags: android, cloudinary

I used cloundinary android sdk in my application. I face two problems  -
1.  when I used upload the image or video using unsinged method in like below code

```
String requestId = MediaManager.get().upload(uri).unsigned("test").option("public_id", uniqueId)
    .callback(new UploadCallback() {
@Override
public void onStart(String requestId) {

    if ((ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBarHorizontal) != null) {
        isPostUploading = true;
        ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_video_icon)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.progressBarDialog)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPreview)).setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPreview)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ((ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBarHorizontal)).setProgress(0);
    }
}
@Override
public void onProgress(String requestId, long bytes, long totalBytes) {
}
@Override
public void onSuccess(String requestId, Map resultData) {
    String img3 = uniqueId + ".jpg";
    String url = MediaManager.get().url().generate(img3);
    new PublishPostTask().execute(desc, role_id, "image", uniqueId, url);
    Log.d("msg", "role_id : " + role_id);
}
@Override
public void onError(String requestId, ErrorInfo error) {
    String er = String.valueOf(error);
    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "error : " + er, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
@Override
public void onReschedule(String requestId, ErrorInfo error) {
}
}).dispatch();
```

it will take too much time to upload I found a reason on debug time staring the request id to onStart method of call black it will take 2-3 mint then onStart to onSuccess it will upload in 15-20 second, why this problem is occur.
and I mention that I have some transformation set on unsinged methodso that can take time for uploading

2. after upload video I call web service and get the transformation url and play on toroplayer in recyclerview. I found null NullPointerException  in logcat . after 1-2 mint refresh the view and again I use the same url it will work. so that mean transformation take time and i asked u how much it will take time

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the upload time:

Cloudinary Android SDK upload method utilizes Android [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html).

JobScheduler is guaranteed to get the upload process done, but since it operates at the system level, it can also use several factors to intelligently schedule the upload process to run with the jobs from other apps.

Whenever an app runs in the background, it consumes some of the device's limited resources, like RAM. 
This can result in an impaired user experience, especially if the user is using a resource-intensive app, such as playing a game or watching video. In most cases, apps can work around these limitations by using JobScheduler jobs. 
This approach lets an app arrange to perform work when the app isn't actively running but still gives the system the leeway to schedule these jobs in a way that doesn't affect the user experience.

So, basically, the JobScheduler will execute the upload process in a way that will not harm the user experience. 
Having said that, in order to tell the JobScheduler to avoid this mechanism, you can use this code:

`MediaManager.get().upload(file/url).constrain(TimeWindow.immediate()).dispatch();`